# Can we provide a good estimation for $(n!)!$?

Tags: approximation, factorial, approximation-theory, stirling-numbers

I was thinking about this

> $$(n!)!$$

for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I wanted to find a suitable approximation, or in any case a very good estimation for this. My first idea was to use Stirling approximation for $(n!)!$ but it leads me to a very confusing algebra. Also I tried to make some approximations but I came up with a negative form.

Is there something we can do to obtain a quite good trend for this?

If you need details of what I wrote, or about what I wrote down on the paper, tell me. It's just a pretty chaotic mess so I avoided to write it down here for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives the series expansion at $n=\infty$ if you exter `(n!)!`. Did you try the lowest order approximation?

Comment: Maybe use the gamma function could help
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: @MateusRocha The gamma function **is** factorials.

Comment: Did a C simulation using 128 bits doubles of $\frac{log_{10}(S(log_{10}(S(n))))}{log_{10}(log_{10}(n!)!)}$ ($log$ to stay within comp limits) and that seems to $\to1$

Answer (score 2):

The bad news is that that nasty algebra does not necessarily give a valid approximation, at least not an approximation of the sort denoted by $\sim$.

Let's say $$S(n)=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n,$$so Stirling's formula says that $$n!\sim S(n)\quad(n\to\infty).$$It follows that $$(n!)!\sim S(n!),$$but it does *not* follow, at least not immediately, that $$(n!)!\sim S(S(n)).$$

Why not? Saying $n!\sim S(n)$ *means* that $$\frac{n!}{S(n)}\to1.$$That certainly implies $$\frac{(n!)!}{S(n!)}\to1,$$but there's no reason to think that it implies that $$\frac{(n!)!}{S(S(n))}\to1.$$

For example, say $f(n)=n^2$ and $g(n)=n^2+n$. Then it's clear that $$f(n)\sim g(n)\quad(n\to\infty),$$but $$\frac{e^{f(n)}}{e^{g(n)}}=e^{-n}\not\to1,$$so $$e^{f(n)}\not\sim e^{g(n)}.$$

Comment: I think it might be worthwhile to point out that the symbol $\sim$ is usually reserved for what you are using $\approx$ for.

Comment: Fine. One, II couldn't recall the TeX for $\sim$, two, my answer was obviously in reply to your answer, where you used $\approx$, evidently without definition...

Comment: You are definitely correct (+1). If you read my answer, I made no claims about it being an asymptotic approximation, though I *really* should have just stated it was not. I will undelete it and just reference your answer in it.

Comment: I agree. It is just plugging in OP's suggestion. I will just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

An easy but bad approximation
for $n!$
is
$(n/e)^n$.

Plugging this into Stirling
in two ways,
$(n!)!
\approx \sqrt{2\pi  (n/e)^n}((n/e)^n/e)^{(n/e)^n}
$
or
$(n!)!
\approx \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n}{e}\right)
^{\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n}
$
where
"$\approx$" means
"somewhere in the neighborhood
but nobody really cares
since the numbers
are so damn large
for large $n$
that we really ought to take the log
anyway."